# How to create a "unified" component type from imported icon and own component in svelte?

Tags: typescript, svelte, typescript-typings, sveltekit

I am using lucide-svelte for my sveltekit app. Besides those lucide icons, I have my own components that only have an  element.

My goal is to create a unified type that I can use for component props so that I can pass either a lucide Icon or my own svg.

This is the type definitions of the lucide-icon type:

```js
/**
 * @license lucide-svelte v0.331.0 - ISC
 *
 * This source code is licensed under the ISC license.
 * See the LICENSE file in the root directory of this source tree.
 */
import type { SvelteComponent } from 'svelte';
import type { SVGAttributes, SvelteHTMLElements } from 'svelte/elements';
export type Attrs = SVGAttributes<SVGSVGElement>;
export type IconNode = [elementName: keyof SvelteHTMLElements, attrs: Attrs][];
export interface IconProps extends Attrs {
    color?: string;
    size?: number | string;
    strokeWidth?: number | string;
    absoluteStrokeWidth?: boolean;
    class?: string;
}
export type IconEvents = {
    [evt: string]: CustomEvent<any>;
};
export type IconSlots = {
    default: {};
};
export type Icon = SvelteComponent<IconProps, IconEvents, IconSlots>;
```

and this is my own icon component :

```js
<script lang="ts">
    export let size = 16;
</script>

<svg width={size} height={size} fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <path
        d=".."
        fill="#6366F1"
    />
</svg>
```

Chatgpt suggested this but I feel like there has to be a better way

```js
// Import your Lucide Icon type
import type { Icon } from 'lucide-svelte';

// Define a type for your custom SVG component props
interface CustomIconProps {
  size: number;
  // Include any other props specific to your SVG components
}

// Define a discriminated union type for the icon props
type AppIconProps = {
  type: 'lucide';
  icon: Icon;
  props?: IconProps; // Assuming IconProps is the type for Lucide icon props
} | {
  type: 'custom';
  component: SvelteComponent; // Your custom SVG component
  props: CustomIconProps;
};
```